# How to have 3 columns with vertical borders at 100 percent for responsive design?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is have a responsive, 3 column design. If the site is being viewed on a phone, the columns should collapse one on top of the other. What I have below will do that however, the problem I cannot seem to solve is with the vertical borders.

If the site is being viewed on a normal desktop computer, there should be 3 columns with two vertical borders at 100% height. What is happening now is that when I shrink the browser, the boxes collapse as they should but *the borders will not go to the floor*.

If the screen is wide enough to handle only two columns, one of the boxes should collapse under and there should only be one vertical border. If the screen is only wide enough for one column, then the other two boxes should collapse under the first box and there should be no border at all at that point.

What I am trying to accomplish is to show the data with borders (if width allows) so that it doesn't look like its all running together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height:100%;
    }
    #wrapper {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      float:left;
    }
    #wrapper div {
      width:33%;
      height:100%;
      min-width:300px;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    #wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
      border-right:1px solid #000;
    }
    #wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
      border-right:1px solid #000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Heard of CSS @media-queries? http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/. Maybe this will do the trick?

Comment: Thanks Kees. I've tried to use that and it works somewhat but I still cannot seem to control the borders. I never thought a border would make my life so difficult.

Comment: Could you post the code you tried?

Comment: from what I understand, if you didn't set a max width to the divs in #wrapper. You will need script to control the borders. Normal responsive @media queries can't help you with that. As there are too many potential widths that the box will have.

Comment: Kooki, I think you're right about @media not helping me here. I have gotten close but no dice. So your recommending a JS solution?

Comment: KeesSonnema, the @media css from Tilwin's example below is what I've added to my code above but it doesn't control the borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css media queries to handle the common scenarios, like

```
// initially all divs will have right boarder by default

@media(width:768px){ // assume that at 768px you'll have 2 divs inline
  #wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
    border-right:0px;
  }
  #wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
    border-right:0px;
  }
}

@media(width:512px){ // assume that at 512px you'll have all 3 divs vertical
  #wrapper div {
    border-right:0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
}
```

etc

Comment: Engage me please. How is this solution going to work if I have say, 2 inline divs with the third div wrapped under? That leaves me with a border-right that only goes down as far as the box on the right.

Comment: `etc` means you can detect a common screen size where you'll have 2 divs inline and 1 at bottom, then you can apply whatever you want, as mentioned in the question: give right margin for the first.

Comment: I'm not following you on this. I have played with `@media` extensively but couldn't seem to get it perfect, close, but not perfect. Can you provide an example, please? If this works, I'd be very pleased.

Comment: Tilwin, I just tried your edits and it's exactly what I was able to do with `@media`. The borders will not span vertically past the bottom of the box. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @NaN i updated the answer. media queries are used to handle common screen resolutions, or you'll have to write separate queries for all available screen sizes which is nearly impossible. for "perfect" solutions you'll need js.

Comment: Tilwin, I was also thinking about using a JS solution. Do you think it would be the best or should I keep trying to find a CSS solution? Fla below recommended Flex Boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend of the compatibility you want to have with old browser (I'm looking at you, IE <= 8). The best new technology to deal with that is [Flex boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), so if you only need to deal with most up-to-date browsers, you have your answer. If you need compatibility, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I should care about IE <= 8 but I don't. I don't even know anyone using IE anymore. So Flex boxes?

Comment: Have a look at [the table of compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility) and make your choice :)

Comment: Thanks Fla, I'm looking there now